# Proving there is no rational number such that square of it is equal to 2.

Tags: proof-verification

I start the proof by assuming there is $m/n \in Q$, expressed in lowest terms, such that $$(m/n)^2=2$$

My textbook tells me to derive a contradiction by showing $m,n$ are both even. 
Here's how I did it.

> $(m/n)^2=2$
>
> $m^2/n^2=2$
>
> $m^2=2n^2$
>
> Hence, $m^2$ is even and $m$ must be even. Then, $m^2=2k$ for some
>   integer $k.$ Plugging $m^2$ back to the equation,
>
> $(2k)^2/n^2=2$
>
> $4k^2=2n^2$
>
> $n^2=2k^2$
>
> Hence, $n^2$ is even so as $n.$ Therefore, it contradicts $m/n$ are in
>   lowest terms.

Is this right way to prove this? I feel I am doing wrong because I am plugging back the equation I got from the equation to the same equation.

Comment: It is the standard way to do it.

Comment: It is correct, just typo, the $m^2=2k$ should be $m=2k$.

Comment: Why are there close votes for this question? Yes, it's a duplicate, but with the [proof-verification] tag it is obvious that the user is asking for feedback *on his/her own proof,* not a pointer to someone else's proof. Closing as a duplicate defeats the entire purpose of this tag.

Comment: The statement in the title is just wrong; there ***is so*** a rational number such that the square of it cannot be $2.$ For instance, $1$ is such a number; $1$ is rational and $1^2\ne2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a classical proof. It can be recast into the following proof comparing  *parity* of powers of $2$ in factorizations (a special case of uniqueness of prime factorizations). Suppose $\, A^{\large 2} = 2B^{\large 2}$

It is straightforward to prove that every natural can be written *uniquely* in the form $\, 2^{\large k} n\,$ for odd $\,n.\,$ So we have $\, A= 2^{\large J} a,\ B = 2^{\large K} b\,$ for $\,a,b\,$ odd. Therefore $\, A^{\large 2}\! = 2 B^{\large 2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,2^{\color{#c00}{\large 2J}} a^{\large 2} = 2^{\color{#0a0}{\large 1+2K}} b^{\large 2}.\ $ But $\,a,b\,$ odd $\,\color{#f2f}\Rightarrow$ $\,a^{\large 2},b^{\large 2}\,$ odd too, which contradicts uniqueness (LHS has $\rm\color{#c00}{even}$ vs. RHS  $\rm\color{#0a0}{odd}$ power of $2).$

To generalize this proof from $\,p = 2\,$ to an arbitrary prime $\,p\,$ would require generalizing the $\,\rm odd^{\large 2} = odd\,$ step that we used above, $ $ i.e. we would need  a proof of the following inference $\ p\nmid a,b\,\color{#f2f}\Rightarrow\, p\nmid a^{\large 2},b^{\large 2}.\ $ Just as for the case $\,p=2,\,$ for any *fixed* prime $\,p\,$ we could prove it by a brute-force case analysis. But to prove the result for *all* primes $\,p\,$ we need something much deeper, e.g. Euclid's lemma $\ p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b\ $ (or closely related results).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361850/242) for "straightforward to prove..."