# Is this proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

Suppose for a contradiction that $\sqrt{3}$ is rational. Thus $\sqrt{3} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ \ {$0$} and $gcd(a,b) = 1$.

$\sqrt{3} = \frac{a}{b} \Rightarrow 3 = \frac{a^2}{b^2} \Rightarrow a^2 = 3b^2: (1)$

By assumption $gcd(a,b) = 1$, thus $b^2\nmid a^2$ as $gcd(a^2,b^2) = 1$, thus $3 \lvert a^2$ thus $3|a$. Thus $a=3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ / {$0$}.

Substituting $a=3k$ into (1):

$3b^2 = (3k)^2 \Rightarrow 9k^2 = 3b^2 \Rightarrow b^2 = 3k^2$.

$k^2 \nmid b^2$ as $k^2 \lvert a^2$ and $gcd(a^2,b^2) = 1$ from $gcd(a,b) = 1$ so if hypothetically $k^2 \lvert a^2$ then $gcd(a^2,b^2) \neq 1$ which is impossible by assumption that $gcd(a,b) = 1$. Thus $3 \lvert b^2$. Thus $3 \lvert b$. $3 \lvert b$ and $3 \lvert a$, but by assumption $gcd(a,b) = 1$, thus this is a contraction. Thus $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Comment: yes, this is a standard proof in the textbook

Comment: You need to prove that if $3|xy$ then $3|x$ or $3|y$. (Which you can do by writing $x$ and $y$ in the form $3n+j$, $0\le j<3$.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ legitimate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470040/is-my-proof-of-the-irrationality-of-sqrt3-legitimate) The answers there show the proof you are trying to write. You do not really want "$b^2$ does not divide $a^2$" you want "$3$ divides $a$" and you don't need $a$ and $b$ relatively prime for that.

Comment: From $a^2=3b^2$ (or $b^2=3k^2$), one could immediately conclude that $3 \mid a^2$ (or $3 \mid b^2$) without needing the assumption that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Also, $b^2 \nmid a^2$ (or $k^2 \nmid b^2$) obviously contradicts $a^2=3b^2$ (or $b^2=3k^2$).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang So its right, just some verboseness? I'm new to writing proofs, so not really sure the amount of detail required.

Comment: How can you do it without the assumption that a and b are coprime? I just can't see it. @EthanBolker

Comment: @Nostradamus You don't need coprimality to see that $3$ divides $a^2$ and hence divides $a$. You do need it in the next step to reach a contradiction when you show $3$ also divides $b$.

Comment: This is one of the most common proofs, which has been discussed here *many* times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441234/242). Please search for answers before posting questions. Also, solution verification quesions are only on-topic if you specify which step of the proof you have doubts about, and why. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine.

Comment: @BillDubuque What if there are multiple aspects of my proof that I am unsure about? I just want to know if my proof is correct or not as a whole.

Comment: "By assumption gcd(a,b)=1, thus b2∤a2 as gcd(a2,b2)=1, thus 3|a2 "  Leave *all* this out.  As $a^2 = 3b^2$ (and $b^2$ is an integer) then $3\mid a^2$.  It has *nothing* to do with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ or $b^2\not\mid a^2$ or anything. Just say "$a^2=3b^2$ thus $3|a^2$".  Then when you say $3|a$ explain why. Then after you show $b^2=3k^2$, leave out all this "k2∤b2 as k2|a2 and gcd(a2,b2)=1 from gcd(a,b)=1 so if hypothetically k2|a2 then gcd(a2,b2)≠1 which is impossible by assumption that gcd(a,b)=1" which has nothing to do with anything and just say "$b^2=3k^2$ and thus $3|b^2$.

Comment: Your proof is valid but be aware it assumes that all rational numbers can be expressed in "lowest terms", and it assumes Euclids lemma (If $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$).  Make sure you are allowed to assume these.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you so much for you reply. But I'm just wondering why 3 | a^2 has nothing to do with gcd(a,b)=1 or b2∤a2 or anything?

Comment: If you have $a^2 = 3b^2$ and $b^2$ is an integer then that means $3|a^2$.  That's the *definition* of $3|a^2$.  That's all.  It doesn't matter that $\gcd(a,b)$.....Also, if $a^2 = 3b^2$ then $b^2$ *DOES* divide $a^2$ because $3$ is an integer and $a^2 =3\times (b^2)$

Comment: BTW why do you think $\gcd(a,b)\implies \gcd(a^2, b^2)$?  If you *DO* know that it makes your entire proof trivial..... If $\frac {a^2}{b^2} = 3$ then *BY DEFINITION* we have $b^2|a^2$ so $b^2$ is a factor of $a^2$.  But as $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$ we must have $b^2 = 1$.  So $b= 1$.  So we have $a^2 =3$ and $3$ is a perfect square.... which it isn't... this is actually why after we prove fundiment principal of arithmetic (that every integer has a unique factorization) we usually just prove "The only rational square roots are integers and only perfect squares have rational square roots" in one swoop.